# how to run maven project from github in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, github

I use eclipse and I want to compile and run this code from gitub https://github.com/openphacts/Validator ,it needs maven project to build it but unfortunately I don't know how to proceed with it. Can someone help me how to get this project into eclipse to run it and test it in my machine please? It's emergency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've checked out the project from github, you need to utilize maven to install the dependencies and build the project. In the root folder of the project (where the pom.xml is located), enter the following in your command line:

```
mvn install
```

More details can be found here: https://maven.apache.org/run-maven/

Additionally, you must first download the maven command line tool: https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

And install it: https://maven.apache.org/install.html